# What is the word to describe the state or condition of being wanted?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

For example, someone has a warrant for arrest.
What is the word to describe the state or condition of being wanted?
Jacques is wanted by the police.

- Because of his ______, he has gone into hiding.

or

- Jacques is ______ / a _______ man.

Obviously, I am looking for another word than 'wanted'.

Comment: “Wanted” seems to cover it.

Comment: Someone wanted by the police is probably a fugitive. A child wanted by his parents is a fortunate child.

Comment: @Xanne I would have answered on the lines of “wanted”, because it is the only word that expresses the condition without also expressing the attribute of fleeing or hiding from justice. Outlaw and fugitive may both be wanted but also are hiding from or fleeing from justice. I have not answered, as a courtesy to Xanne, who should have done so first.

Comment: Go ahead, @Anton. A person wanted by some authorities may or may not be hiding or fleeing. Or has already fled, perhaps even fled the jurisdiction. So many possibilities.So it depends on who wants whom for what.

Comment: @Xanne I haven't the heart. You deserve the credit :)

Comment: 'Fugitiveness' is probably obsolete, and defaulted to 'ephemeralness' anyway. 'Fugitivity' exists, but defaults to an inappropriate sense.

Comment: "fugitive status" might work...

Answer (score 1):

While not a single word, maybe you could use [at large](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/at_large)

> (especially of a criminal or dangerous animal) at liberty; escaped or not yet captured.

Comment: It's a delightful idiom. I suppose it's extragrammatical [preposition + adjective], but it might be analysed as a strange usage of 'large'.  // When they've been cornered, we don't say they're 'at small'.